# Visual Studio 2019 Mac removes Android Settings and cannot revert

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-2019

I am using Vs 2019 on Windows and Vs 2019 mac for the same Xamarin forms project. When I open project on VS 2019 mac, Android project has some auto changes on Droid.cs files and comparing what was changed is the result below in the image

[image]

You can see that in both debug and release configuration AndroidLinkSkip , EnableMultidex and enableProguard are removed.

Interesting part is that when i look at the UI on Options part, settings are checked there.

I am not able to revert those changes also. If i select revert changes, VS will check them out again.

What is the problem with VS 2019 mac?

[image]

EDIT: it looks like that latest update of VS2019 windows changed settings before it was called "enabled proguard" as in the screenshot from Mac. Now they call it as "Code Shrinker". This causes conflict between Vs2019 windows and Mac. 
Beside I tried using this option only by removing old setting for proguard but it doesnt work. It throws exception. If i run it on VS2017 using old settings it works fine. I dont see any good documentation for this Breking change.

[image]

Comment: Can you please report an issue using `Help -> Report a Problem` within the IDE?

Comment: @JonDouglas i already created a ticket there but i dont believe it will be fixed. in my opinion this is a serious issue and it turned to be even more. i created a github issue also. proguard settings on mac doesnt work at all.

Comment: Can you please links to these items so others and myself can upvote and look further into them? Thanks in advance!